# How to check if div is visible and then hide it on click anywhere else except of this div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've got image with ID h-plus.

When it's clicked it adds class d-block to image and close arrow.

When someone click close arrow then image and arrow dissaper.

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#h-plus-1").click(function() {  
    $('#h-image-1').addClass("d-block");
    $('#h-close-arrow-1').addClass("d-block");
  });
});
  $(function() {
  $("#h-close-arrow-1").click(function() {     
    $('#h-image-1').removeClass("d-block");
    $('#h-close-arrow-1').removeClass("d-block");
  });
});
```

What I try to achive is to write jQuery script which will check if h-image have class d-block and if have this class then hide it when user will click anywhere except of h-image. Some sort of lightbox but without lightbox overlay effect.

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: Trying to use it: 
 $(document).click(function(event) { 
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if(!$target.closest('#h-image-1').length && 
  $('#h-image-1').hasClass("d-block")) {
    $('#h-image-1').removeClass("d-block");
    $('#h-close-arrow-1').removeClass("d-block");
  }        
}); 
But wont work